# Duplicate records are created in case of concurrent requests

Tags: php, laravel, locking, lumen

I have two tables `orders` and `driver_orders`.The sample code is :

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try{
//check if the order status is pending.If the status is other than pending then one of the driver has accepted the order.
$fetch_order = $this->order->where([
    ['id',$id],
    ['status','pending']
])->lockForUpdate()->first();

if(!fetch_order){
    throw new Exception('Order is already assigned to another driver.');
}
$driver_id = Auth::id();
//checks if logged in driver has pending order to be delivered.
$check_user_pending_order = $this->driver_order->where([
    ['driver_id', $driver_id ],
    ['status','!=','delivered']
])->lockForUpdate()->first();

if($check_user_pending_order){
    throw new Exception('You have pending order to be delivered.');
}

$data['order_id'] = $fetch_order->id;
$data['driver_id'] = $driver_id;
$data['amount'] = $fetch_order->amount;
$data['status'] = 'assigned';

//create record in driver_order table

$this->driver_order->create($array);

//update the status in order table

$fetch_order->update([
    'status' => 'assigned'
]);

DB::commit();

return response()->json([
    'status' => '200',
    'message' => 'Order successfully assigned. Get ready to deliver the order.'
]);


}
catch(\Exception $ex){
return response()->json([
    'status' => '403',
    'message' => $ex->getMessage()
],403);
}
```

The issue is I am getting concurrent request which tends to create duplicate records for the same order in `driver_orders` table. I used the locking but it does not solve the problem as well. Please suggest me the way to tackle the above mention issue.

Comment: Shouldn't making the order_id unique in the driver_orders table prevent an order being assigned more than once?

Comment: well admin can reassign to another driver by changing the previous driver assigned order status to unassigned. So making the order_id unique wont solve the case.

Comment: Interesting case. Never got similar problem but. Have you try to add `UNIQUE` index to column `driver_id` and `order_id` on `driver_orders` table?

Comment: well making unique cannot fix the issue cause there is important feature that admin can assign those order to another driver  or same driver as well making those previous assigned driver status unassigned.